# Using HTML when creating a PDF in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, pdf, dompdf

I'm creating a website using Laravel with a feature that allows you to download a PDF with details from the page you're viewing (i.e. training course).

I use the **[barryvdh/laravel-dompdf](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf)** package.

**Controller**

```
$data["overview"] = $course[0]['overview__c'];

$pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.course', $data);
```

The $data array is passed over into the 'pdf.course' blade file and the values inside contain HTML code/tags.

**views > pdf > course.blade.php**

```
<img src="{{asset('images/pdf-logo.fw.png')}}" style="margin-bottom: 25px;">

{{ $overview__c }}
```

When the PDF is created/downloaded, the data inside doesn't render the HTML code but instead just displays the tags, leaving the PDF completely unformatted.

It appears that any HTML code has to be part of the blade file and can't come from the $data being passed to it.

Does anyone have any solutions or workarounds for me to try?

Comment: dump your HTML & PHP code here

Comment: Please shows your `pdf.course` view file.

Comment: how are you printing `data` in your blade file??

Comment: @SumonMahmud I've added all the relevant code

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya Done

Comment: @zahidhasanemon See above, I've made an edit

Comment: @CraigyCraigo I think you have made mistake to load the data 
Instead of `{{ $overview__c }}` you can got data in the `{{ $overview }}`

and one more guide
Please try with the add https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf#tip-utf-8-support this code in your .blade file

Comment: Sorry @ChiragViradiya -  I don't understand.

Comment: @CraigyCraigo Try with below code in your `course.blade.php` file

`
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<img src="{{asset('images/pdf-logo.fw.png')}}" style="margin-bottom: 25px;">

{{ $overview }}
`

Comment: @ChiragViradiya Didn't work :(

Comment: @CraigyCraigo can you try `{!! $data !!}` ?

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya {!! !!} was the solution! :)

Comment: @CraigyCraigo You are missing the HTML & BODY tags in your `course.blade.php`

Here you final `course.blade.php` will be like
```<html>
   <body>
      <img src="{{asset('images/pdf-logo.fw.png')}}" style="margin-bottom: 25px;">

{{ $overview }}
   </body>
</html>```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `{!! !!}` to display unescaped data

```
{!! $overview !!}
```

you can find the doc [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#displaying-data)

Answer (score 1):

Controller

```
$data["overview"] = $course[0]['overview__c'];

$pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.course', $data);
```

Blade.php

```
{{$data}}
```

*And Image*

```
<img src="{{asset('images/pdf-logo.fw.png')}}" style="margin-bottom: 25px;">

{{!! $overview__c !!}}
```

Comment: Thanks Vikas, this is exactly how I'm doing it.

Comment: But if $data contains HTML tags (which it does), it prints the tags out instead of using them to format the text

Comment: please select this answer if it help for you thank you@CraigyCraigo

Answer (score 1):

```
    Bro by this u can render your html in pdf
```

In your Controller:

```
    $data["overview"] = $course[0]['overview__c'];
    $html = view('vendor.tcsprint', compact('data'))->render();
    $pdf->loadHTML($html);
    return $pdf->download('Order-'.$tcs['invoice_no'].'.pdf');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in so many ways

```
1. {!!html_entity_decode($overview)!!}

2. {!! $overview !!}

3. {!! nl2br($overview) !!}
```

Comment: Simply using {!! !!} was enough! Thanks